# Display HTML5 video with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am trying to make a plugin for displayng html5 video as follows:

```
(function ($) {
    // plugin definition
    $.fn.myvideo = function (options) {
        // build main options before element iteration
        var defaults = {
            theme: 'normal',
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        // iterate and reformat each matched element
        return this.each(function () {
            var $myvideo = $(this);
            addvideo();

            function addvideo() {
                var addvideo = $('<video controls="controls" width="480" height="208" id="video2"><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis""><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2""></video>');
                $(addvideo).append('body');
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This is how I call it:

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#video').htmlvideo();
        });
 </script>
```

This is a link to call the video:

```
<a href='#' id='video'><span>Launch video</span></a>
```

And it dosent display anyting :(

Can anyone say what the mistake is?

And how do I display the video without the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are re-wrapping the `addVideo`

```
 function addvideo() {
                var addvideo = $('<video controls="controls" width="480" height="208" id="video2"><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis""><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2""></video>');

                addvideo.append('body');//<-- here addvideo is already wrapped in $
                               ^
                //may be you wanted to use appendTo
                //addvideo.appendTo('body');
            }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CSTPv/4/)

Comment: @3nigma-Thanks for your reply.I understood where I went wrong as you mentioned above.But after removing that line it still not showing up.Here is my fiddle demo. http://jsfiddle.net/CSTPv/1/

Comment: you havent selected jquery in the fiddle

Comment: @DotNetter i have added a demo in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code is all wrong. First of all, you don't need a link, you're already trying to execute htmlvideo() on document ready, but your `$('#video')` doesn't return anything because an element with ID "video" doesn't exist in your HTML.

Here's a working code:

```
(function ($) {
// plugin definition
$.fn.myvideo = function (options) {
    // build main options before element iteration
    var defaults = {
        theme: 'normal',
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    // iterate and reformat each matched element
    return this.each(function () {
        var $myvideo = $(this);
        addvideo();

        function addvideo() {                  
            var addvideo = $('<video controls="controls" width="480" height="208" id="video2"><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis""><source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2""></video>');
            $(addvideo).appendTo('#vid');
        }
    });
};

    $(function () {
        $('#vid').myvideo();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

This is the sample HTML (you don't really need a div, you can just attach the element to body like you did in your question):

```
<div id="vid"></div>
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PCNeJ/

I've inserted some `console.log()` statements that you can follow in a tool like Firebug and erase them later.

Comment: dalbaeb-Thanks for the explanation-I am at the starting point as you said may be my code is wrong?Thats the way I am trying to learn something about jquery.Anyways +1 for the fiddle demo.